# NextJS Middleware.ts file not triggered

Tags: reactjs, next.js, middleware

I have a NextJS React Project. It has the following file structures:
src/app contains all pages. There is no src/app/pages. In my setup, for example, the login page would be called by "/login" where src/app/login/page.tsx is the page being rendered.
I added a middleware.ts to src/app/ so it is in the format "src/app/middleware.ts".

```
"paths": {
     "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
 },
"include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
"exclude": ["node_modules"]
```

However the issue is that it is not being triggered. I have attached my tsconfig below:

Any help on this issue would be great

I've tried adding a pages folder in src/app/pages. I've tried changing the tsconfig file as well but not sure if I've done it completely right. I also tried to put middleware.ts at the same level as app but I got the following error

Error: Invalid middleware found.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :**

> *I added a middleware.ts to src/app/ so it is in the format "src/app/middleware.ts"*

**Cause :**

- Improper Middlware file location `src/app/middleware.ts` you placed it inside of `app`,
- `middleware.ts` should be at same level(outside) of `app` folder,
- If you have `src` then inside of `src` folder.

**Solution :**

- `middleware.ts` should be outside of app.

**If you have** `src` then `src/middleware.ts` :

```
projectName
├── src
    ├── middleware.ts
    ├── app
```

**If you don't have** `src` then `projectName/middleware.ts` :

```
projectName
├── app
├── middleware.ts
```

**Please Read :**

- **Middleware Convention :**  https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#convention

> ***If you have any doubts, then please leave a comment (I will update answer if necessary)***